# how to get a CSV from an API and map it into a model

Tags: django, csv, django-models, import, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and I want to get data via an API in CSV format and import it to my models but I don't know how to do this properly.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [django import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export)